# How to make snow golems do damage?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a single player world, and I'm trying to make a game in which two players try to attack and destroy each other's bases (represented by and iron golem and a ravager in cages). I'm trying to allow them to use mobs (snow golems and skeletons) to aid them in their endeavors. However, I am having trouble making the snow golems do damage. I'm going to try the following command tomorrow, and I'll post an answer if it works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this with commands. **Is there any way to make snow golems do damage to mobs who aren't blazes?**

Note: I'm playing on an Xbox, so less is more when it comes to character count for the command. :)

```
/execute @e[type=snowball] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=!snow_golem, rm=0, r=.5] ~ ~ ~ summon arrow ~ ~1 ~
```

Comment: Im not posting this as an answer since it isn't a command like you requested, but I have heard of a method where (assuming the golems are stationary,) you can light their snowballs on fire by having it pass through a fire when it's shot out from it, causing it to do fire damage.

Comment: Thanks! Although you are right in that that is not what I'm looking for, that may be helpful in another aspect of my game. 

Comment: To build on what what @ChocolateChara said, could you make a fire in front of the golem just for the duration of the snow ball passing through it? As in make the fire at ~1 ~ ~ of the golem's location?

Comment: @Diehe I don't know much about commands, only technical methods that can be done without commands and such. But i'm sure it's possible with something considering how people have made insane stuff using commands.

Comment: @Diehe considering that the golems could be facing any direction (E,W,N,S,NE,NW,SE,SW), and fire would have to be in a block, that wouldn't work.

Comment: Perhaps you could simply run a command to constantly make any snowballs on fire?

Comment: I don't know of a way to set entities on fire other than either 1. using /entitydata (a Java only feature) or 2. summoning some other entity (e.g. flaming arrow, fireball) above/at them, which is what I'm trying to do in the first place.